# Change the color of entire tikz picture imported with input

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have a small image I want to reuse in another tikz picture.

Let's say file img.tex contains:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and I want it to appear in several places in an other image

```
\newcommand\mycuteimage[1]{\scalebox{#1}{\input{img}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (10, 1);
    \foreach \x in {2,5,9}
    {
        \node at (\x - 0.5, 0.5) {\mycuteimage{0.1}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can I somehow set the color of the inserted image, say sometimes red, sometimes blue?

Example:

```
\mycuteimage[blue]{0.1}
```

I've tried to use

```
{\color{blue} \mycuteimage{0.1}}
```

but it only changes the color of lines I didn't specify a color for, i.e., if, some elements were red in the original image they will remain red.

Comment: Why do you have to make a whole `img.tex` just to contain a figure? I think you should add the figure directly to the command definition.

Comment: i intend to reuse it in more images

Comment: This nests `tikzpicture`s, which should be avoided. You could use a `pic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposal nests `tikzpicture`s, which should be avoided. Ti*k*Z has `pic`s for such purposes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
my cute pic/.style={code={
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (10, 1);
    \edef\LstColors{{"red","green","blue"}}
    \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0]in {2,5,9}
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\LstColors[\Y]}
        \pic at (\X - 0.5, 0.5) [scale=0.1,color=\mycolor]{my cute pic};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`pics` also take parameters.

Comment: And the result is ... the same. It colors only color-unspecified lines. So, if I have colored lines in original code - it stays the same. On the other hand \input works in code section !!